# How to smooth a stairstep-like graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The stairstep-look of the graph is unintentional. When I plot the same-sized vectors `Arb` and `V` (`plot (Arb, V, 'r')`) I get the following graph:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q5oe.png)

To make it smoother, I tried using 1-D data interpolation, `interp1`, as follows:

```
xq = 0:0.001:max(Arb);
Vq = interp1 (Arb, V, xq);
plot (xq, Vq);
```

However, I get this error message:

```
Error using interp1>reshapeAndSortXandV (line 416)
X must be a vector.

Error in interp1 (line 92)
    [X,V,orig_size_v] = reshapeAndSortXandV(varargin{1},varargin{2})
```

Comment: How would interpolation assist in smoothing? You'd just get more points in the same shape. Try some sort of fit line (if you know the data should indeed be linear), plotted over the top of the individual data points.

Comment: Have you tried with the 'smooth' function?

Comment: I have. It makes very little difference to the general look of the graph. It only makes the edges of the steps a little rounder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interp1` will use linear interpolation on your data so it won't help you much. One thing you can try is to use a cubic spline with `interp1` but again given the nature of the data I don't think it will help much. e.g.

> **Alternative 1**. Cubic Spline

```
xq = 0:0.001:max(Arb);
Vq = interp1 (Arb, V, xq, 'spline');
plot (xq, Vq);
```

> **Alternative 2.** Polynomial fit

Another alternative you can try is, polynomial interpolation using [`polyfit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html). e.g.

```
p = polifit(Arb, V, 2); % I think a 2nd order polynomial should do
xq = 0:0.001:max(Arb);
Vq = polyval(p, xq);
plot (xq, Vq);
```

> **Alternative 3**. Alpha-beta filter

Last but not least, another thing to try is to use an smoothing [`alpha-beta filter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_beta_filter) on your `V` data. One possible implementation can be:

```
% x is the input data
% a is the "smoothing" factor from [0, 1]
% a = 0 full smoothing
% a = 1 no smoothing
function xflt  = alphaBeta(x, a)
    xflt = zeros(1,length(x));
    xflt(1) = x(1);

    a = max(min(a, 1), 0); % Bound coefficient between 0 and 1;

    for n = 2:1:length(x);
        xflt(n) = a * x(n) + (1 - a) * xflt(n-1);
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
plot (Arb, alphaBeta(V, 0.65), 'r')
```